# How did they shoot this tongue pulling scene?

Tags: film-techniques, robin-hood-men-in-tights

This pulling the tongue comedy scene belongs to **[Robin Hood: Men In Tights](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107977/)**:

[image: Tongue pulling scene]

How this scene was shot?

Comment: Biting down into a fake stretchy tongue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Undoubtedly a **fake tongue**, similar those available online: